# Xcode Automatic Signing for macOS Developer ID

Tags: xcode, xcode8, code-signing, osx-gatekeeper, xcode9

I'm trying to sign a macOS app with Developer ID / Gatekeeper using Xcode 8 or 9.  In the past, I've always done this by scripting `codesign`.  But now I want to add a iCloud entitlement, and that seems to require signing by Xcode.   The page on [Developer ID in Apple's *App Distribution Guide*](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/DistributingApplicationsOutside/DistributingApplicationsOutside.html) still shows what I remember from an older Xcode version.  In Xcode 8 or 9, you see there is no more *Developer ID* radio buton…

[image: Target Info]

Is the above a correct configuration for Developer ID?  (I don't think so,  but I don't see any other options!)

After Product > Archive completes, the produced *BookMacster* archive seems to be a *Generic Xcode Archive* instead of a app archive…

[image: Organizer Window]

And the choices it gives me when I click *Export* don't seem appropriate an app…

[image: Export… sheet]

If I *Save Built Products*, I get a directory structure which contains all of the other executables and helpers in the package, but not the BookMacster.app!